# Joining dataframes with different datetime frequencies

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have some sparse higher frequency data (unevenly spaced) and some low frequency data (daily).
How can I join this data and append corresponding low frequency data columns to the higher frequency data if it falls on that day?

One way would be to create a custom apply function and check each datum's YMD and look up the corresponding low frequency data, but that seems pretty inefficient.

Here's an example DataFrame which demonstrates the problem:

```
df1 = DataFrame(dict(date1 = date_range(start='20100101', periods=48, freq='H'),value1=range(48)))
df2 = DataFrame(dict(date2 = date_range(start='20100101', periods=2, freq='D'),value2=range(2)))
```

I've tried pd.merge and and pd.join but they don't match and produce NaNs.

```
merge(df1,df2,left_on='date1',right_on='date2',how='outer')

                 date1  value1      date2  value2
0  2010-01-01 00:00:00       0 2010-01-01       0
1  2010-01-01 01:00:00       1        NaT     NaN
2  2010-01-01 02:00:00       2        NaT     NaN
3  2010-01-01 03:00:00       3        NaT     NaN
...
1  2010-01-01 01:00:00       1 2010-01-02       1
24 2010-01-02 00:00:00      24        NaT     NaN
25 2010-01-02 01:00:00      25        NaT     NaN
...
30 2010-01-02 06:00:00      30        NaT     NaN
31 2010-01-02 07:00:00      31        NaT     NaN
```

The output I'm hoping for should have value2 be 0 for everything on the 1st and 1 for everything on the 2nd:

```
                 date1  value1      date2  value2
0  2010-01-01 00:00:00       0 2010-01-01     0
1  2010-01-01 01:00:00       1 2010-01-01     0
2  2010-01-01 02:00:00       2 2010-01-01     0
3  2010-01-01 03:00:00       3 2010-01-01     0
...
29 2010-01-02 05:00:00      29 2010-01-02     1
30 2010-01-02 06:00:00      30 2010-01-02     1
31 2010-01-02 07:00:00      31 2010-01-02     1
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for resample?

Comment: It would help if you give two example (small) dataframe (like a few rows each) along with the desired output you are looking for. At the moment this question is too vague.

Comment: @AndyHayden, Sorry about that, added an example

Comment: @wflynny I tried pd.merge and df1.join

Comment: @Envy that's much better, thanks! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: you can do this super cleanly with a merge (assuming no overlapping columns):

```
In [41]: df1['date2'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['date1']).normalize()

In [42]: pd.merge(df1, df2).head()
Out[42]:
                date1  value1      date2  value2
0 2010-01-01 00:00:00       0 2010-01-01       0
1 2010-01-01 01:00:00       1 2010-01-01       0
2 2010-01-01 02:00:00       2 2010-01-01       0
3 2010-01-01 03:00:00       3 2010-01-01       0
4 2010-01-01 04:00:00       4 2010-01-01       0
```

---

Original answer, which I thought *may* be more efficient. is to do this with a reindex:

Just to make things easier let's set date2 as the index:

```
In [11]: df2 = df2.set_index('date2')
```

Now reindex on the start of the day (with normalize, in 0.15 you'll be able to use `.dt.normalize()`):

```
In [12]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.date1).normalize()
Out[12]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2010-01-01, ..., 2010-01-02]
Length: 48, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [13]: df2.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.date1).normalize()).head()
Out[13]:
            value2
2010-01-01       0
2010-01-01       0
2010-01-01       0
2010-01-01       0
2010-01-01       0
```

You have to use the values to avoid pandas realigning on the index:

```
In [14]: df1['value2'] = df2.reindex(pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.date1).normalize()).values

In [15]: df1.head()
Out[15]:
                date1  value1  value2
0 2010-01-01 00:00:00       0       0
1 2010-01-01 01:00:00       1       0
2 2010-01-01 02:00:00       2       0
3 2010-01-01 03:00:00       3       0
4 2010-01-01 04:00:00       4       0
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work if my lower frequency data wasn't days? It seems that normalize doesn't take any parameters, for example, if my low frequency data was on a monthly basis, or bi-weekly.

Comment: @Envy Yes. The method is `.to_period('M')` rather than `normalize()` (should work with '2W' too, I think you can also specify which day it W-SUN etc. see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets)